# FM radio permission issues android 5.0

Tags: android, permissions

Just to learn the deodex/decompiling in android, I decided to play with some system app. For this I decided to make some minor UI changes to the native FM Radio app on my phone. The phone was running android 4.4. I first rooted my phone, decompiled the radio app, made some changes to it and then placed it in /system/app folder removing the old apk and it worked fine. Later just for curiosity, I made a radio widget (re-using the code from native app). Installed that widget on my device and it worked for me.

Recently I got a new phone running android 5.0. I decompiled its native radio app. Made an app re-using some of native fm app's code and installed it as user app. The application installs and runs but the radio is not working. The phone is not rooted and it gives me permission issues for FM radio. In logs I can see error **permission denied on /dev/fm**

The old phone which was running 4.4, I got a similar one which was never rooted and installed my radio widget and it actually worked (so 4.4 with or without root the fm works)

I checked the permissions on /dev/fm which are as following

old phone 4.4 : crw-rw----- system    media    fm
new phone 5.4 : crw-rw----- system    media    fm

The permissions are same on both but still I get permission denied on android 5.0.

I am not sure if there are some permission changes (for media user/group maybe) in android 5.0. Can someone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Selinix related. I see similar issue with fm radio app. Tried to install radio app from a custom rom imto tje stock rom (same phone). Radio worked in custom but not in stock.
Logcat show /dev/fm was denked access to tmpfs, permissive=0.  So i  made stock run in permissive and fm radio works

In your case android 4 ,comes "permissive" and android 5 comes "enforce"